# Returning a table in firebird 3.0 with stored function or stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, return-type, stored-functions, firebird-3.0

I'm trying to write a stored procedure/function that returns me a table with one or multiple rows of data.

The returned data depends on a variable shown in the following sql statement:

```
  SELECT * FROM table_name AS SD WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT DISTINCT S.PARENT_ID FROM table_name AS S 
  WHERE S.COMPONENT_ID = 10011 AND S.CARRIER_GROUP_ID = X AND SD.SD_ID = S.PARENT_ID)
```

So far I have seen that something is done like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_test_function (X INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
   (SELECT * FROM table_name AS SD WHERE EXISTS
      (SELECT DISTINCT S.PARENT_ID FROM table_name AS S 
      WHERE S.COMPONENT_ID = 10011 AND S.CARRIER_GROUP_ID = X AND SD.SD_ID = S.PARENT_ID));
```

Afterwards you call the function/procedure with a X value. I know that there is something wrong with the returns type but I don't know what.

Can anyone help?

Comment: As far as I know, Firebird now supports *scalar* functions, not table-valued functions:  https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-psql-funcs.html.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Firebird has selectable stored procedures, which are somewhat like table-valued functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [selectable stored procedure](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-psql-storedprocs-selectable). Firebird requires you to explicitly declare the columns the stored procedure returns, so something like `returns table` is not an option. For example:

```
create procedure sp_test_procedure (x integer) 
  returns (column1 integer, column2 varchar(50))
as
begin
  for select value1, value2 
      from table_name SD
      where exists (
        SELECT DISTINCT S.PARENT_ID 
        FROM table_name AS S 
        WHERE S.COMPONENT_ID = 10011 
        AND S.CARRIER_GROUP_ID = :X 
        AND SD.SD_ID = S.PARENT_ID)
      into column1, column2
  do
  begin
    suspend;
  end
end
```

You will need to explicitly map the columns, so a simple `select *` is not a good idea.

Note the use of [`for select`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-psql-forselect), which selects zero or more rows and iterates over the cursor, and [`suspend`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-psql-suspend), which outputs a row to be fetched from the stored procedure (in this case for each row of the cursor).

You can produce values from this procedure like:

```
select column1, column2
from sp_test_procedure(10)
```

Comment: I tried your approach and it works great. Thanks for your help.